# changing prompt color in bash in konsole

Tags: bash, colors, konsole

I change the color of my prompt in the console by changing the `PS1` variable in my `.bashrc` like this:

```
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}$COLOR_USER\u@$COLOR_HOST\h:$COLOR_PWD\w>$COLOR_ORDER"
```

`COLOR_`… are variables.

But it gets overwritten by the console color scheme.
How can i stop the console from overwriting my `.bashrc` settings?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the ansii colour codes you'll be using are numbers, not colours. So for example maybe colour 3 is green by default and you're saying to use colour 3. Whereas konsole's colour schemas map different colours to the numbers. So you can either change your colour numbers to find something you like, or else you can in konsoles settings, look for a menu to select a "default" colour scheme which has the traditional number-to-colour mappings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications running in the terminal, such as the shell, send [escape sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_) to the terminal to change the appearance of subsequent output. The escape sequence to change the character attributes is `CSI Pm m` where `CSI` stands for the two-character sequence `ESC [` (which can be written in bash as `$'\e['`) and *Pm* is a sequence that determines what to change.

Presumably your configuration uses the 8 standard colors, i.e. `$COLOR_USER` is something like `$'\e[31m'` to get red text. The appearance of standard colors can be chosen freely by the terminal. If you use a theme in Konsole, it may tweak the colors however it pleases. Good themes would just pick a decent shade but some Konsole themes completely change them.

You can use an escape sequence that specifies a color by its red-green-blue components: `CSI 3 8 ; 2 ; Pr ; Pg ; Pb m` (where *Pr*, *Pg* and *Pb* are the red-green-blue components respectively, on a scale of 0 to 255). Konsole will respect that. For example, to get the user name in red:

```
COLOR_USER=$'\e[38;2;128;0;0m'
```

Alternatively, use a color theme that respects the colors that the application specified, instead of completely messing them up.