# Change color of root user prompt

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

I wanted to enable color in the shell as the root user on Ubuntu Server 22.04 after having typed `sudo -s`.  I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477748/syntax-highlighting-in-vim-turned-on-for-user-but-off-for-root) question which led me to the solution of uncommenting the `force_color_prompt=yes` in the file `/root/.bashrc`.  This worked well, but I'm now wondering if there is also a way to change the color of the root prompt to give better indication that I'm operating as root.

Here is what I have:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

**Update:**

For completeness here is my original `PS1` line:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

And here is the modified `PS1` line which gave me the results I desired:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using bash, because you're using .bashrc. If that's wrong, please fix my tag :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller that is correct

Comment: Before moving around with a loaded root on your hands take a look [at this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/which-is-the-safest-way-to-get-root-privileges-sudo-su-or-login)

Comment: @PabloA Thanks, that is a nice thesis. Kind of left me with more questions though. I would love to see a "good, better, best" breakdown of how to handle sudo and root permissions to protect against the most common attack vectors. "Best" would be the "one-time keys" that were mentioned in the accepted answer, but realistically only large orgs will be doing that. We limit the `sudo` group to a minimal amount of trusted users and have no actual users in the `root` group. Sensitive files have `root:root` ownership usually with X00 permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; you can [color codes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344413/changing-prompt-color-in-bash-in-konsole) in your prompt PS1 variable; for example, in your `/root/.bashrc` you could `PS1="\e[38;2;128;0;0m[\u@\h \W]\$ "` or similar.

There's also much richer frameworks for shell prompt customization, but they are a bit more prolific (and, in my humble experience, mature) for `zsh` than for `bash`. You can try [`oh my BASH!`](https://ohmybash.nntoan.com/), but frankly, if you do that, I'd recommend trying `zsh` instead of `bash` as your default shell, paired with [`powerlevel10k`](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) for better prompts, and if you need your shell to do things like help you with a lot of tasks, even `oh-my-zsh` (which `oh my BASH!` is a clone of).

Comment: Thanks! I knew about oh my zsh, but didn't realize there was a bash port.  The syntax of what you proposed was slightly different than what was in my `.bashrc` file, so I updated my question for completeness.